# date during your collection period saw the greatest number of matching tweets

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello i want to write a query which tells me the great number of tweets collect on a particular day like my question is

"date during your collection period saw the greatest number of matching tweets"

i have collected data from tweetcatcher but didnt know which query i use

Comment: You should add to your question a relevant sample of the data, your expected result based on that sample, and what you've tried so far. As is, this question is unlikely to get any answers.

Comment: SELECT date, MAX(tweets)   
FROM Course 
GROUP BY date;   I TRIED THIS BUT IT NOR WORKING  COULD YOU HELP MEE SORT OUT FOR THIS

Comment: What's not working about that query? Not much to go off of, what's in the `tweets` field?

Comment: Please add code and table structures (table name, column names and data types) as well as sample data. Recommend you review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on, but based on your comment

```
SELECT date, Tweets=count(*) FROM Course GROUP BY date Order by 2 Desc
```

You could also add **Select Top 1 ...** if you want only one record.